# cURL not working correct!

Tags: php, curl

I have a question about cURL. I am using cURL with this function:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Only this was causing an error: "Message: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set"

So I asked my hosting provider to fix this, and they did. But, and this is really stupid, they put a "curl" file in my bin directory. And I have no idea how to include this in my php script :S.

Never done it before, but can anybody help me. I am really stuck. I hope I posted enough info!

Tnx in advanced!

---

Tnx for all the great replies. But How would I fit "exec()" in this code?

```
    // create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $articleUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);

    // grab URL and pass it to $grabArticle
    $grabArticle = curl_exec($ch);
```

---

Edit 2:
Oké, I almost got it working :). It is working just fine when I run it in putty, but in my php script nothing happens :(

I run this:

```
$grabArticle = exec('/home/twittern/bin/curl -L -m 30 -w url_effective --max-redirs 5 http://fok.nl/415758');
echo $grabArticle;
```

Any thing I am doing wrong?

Comment: So, they only gave you a curl executable? It sounds like they expect you to run it with`exec`.

Comment: Re your update, you'll have to re-build those options on the command line, see http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: Ah, that is F*cked up :S. So it would be something like: $grabArticle = exec('/home/twittern/bin/curl ' . $articleUrl . '-A <Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)> -L');

Comment: Very stupid of me, but I did not look at the exec function very good :). Tnx for all the help, It's just working fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the built-in cURL functions within PHP, they are asking you to use the external command-line version.

Use the PHP [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to call the program, the command line options can be found on the [curl man page](http://man.cx/curl%281%29).

Given that you probably need the response in full, you may need to use [passthru()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) with output buffering or save the output to a (temporary) file.

Answer (score 1):

PHP curl doesn't rely on a curl bin being available. (PHP supports curl by default since 4.0.2)

Your hosting provider just needs to make sure your PHP ini has `safe_mode` switched off.

But given the way the handled this (giving you a curl binary) it looks like you should use `exec()` to call it.

Personally, I'd recommend you find a better host.

Comment: Agree, but another host is not really an option :).

Answer (score 1):

Your provider sucks. Call them back and make them recompile php to include curl support.

Otherwise you are stuck with calling curl directly.

```
$result = exec("/bin/curl http://www.foobar.com");
```

Comment: He has curl support compiled in, just he has safe_mode or open_basedir in effect.  If it is shared hosting, they are unlikely to turn these security measures off on demand.

Comment: I agree with Byron. The suck :(. Really weird, because normaly they are very helpfull. It is a reseller hosting platform BTW :)

Comment: The funny thing about this is that if they left safe mode on, `exec()` won't work either, will it?

Comment: That is no problem, because safemode is off :)